# JQuery UI AutoComplete - how to store the displayed value as input field value. Laravel 9 platform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery-UI in my laravel application for autocomplete lookup in my laravel app.

Below are my source data

```
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| pid | eid | cid   | candidate                                                 |
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 104 |   2 | 10401 | Alice Student - Deputy President (Finance & Services)     |
| 101 |   2 | 10101 | Alice Student - Imperial College Union President          |
| 104 |   2 | 10402 | Bob Student - Deputy President (Finance & Services)       |
| 101 |   2 | 10102 | Bob Student - Imperial College Union President            |
| 108 |   2 | 10802 | Bashabi Sarker - Black & Minority Ethnic Students Officer |
| 101 |   2 | 10801 | Bashabi Sarker - Imperial College Union President         |
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is my code in controller to get the data.

```
$candidatenames = [];
foreach($positions as $position){
    $candidatenames[] = array("value"=>$position->cid,"label"=>$position->candidate,"pid"=>$position->pid,"eid"=>$position->eid);
}

   echo json_encode($candidatenames);
```

This is my autocomplete form [image]

As you can see the autocomplete function is working fine. and the data are displaying in correct input field.

But **how to set the displayed values as input field values. currently when I submit the form the values are not posted.**

This my code for the form

```
<form action= {{ route('complaints.store') }} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <input type="text" id='candidate_search'>
        <input type="text" id='cid'>
        <input type="text" id='pid' value="">
        <input type="text" id='eid'>
        <input class="button secondary" type="submit" name="save" value="Save all changes"></li>


</form>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#candidate_search").autocomplete({
            source: "{{url('/get-candidates')}}",

            select: function (event, ui) {
                // Set selection
                $('#candidate_search').val(ui.item.label); 
                $('#cid').val(ui.item.value); 
            $('#pid').val(ui.item.pid); 
            $('#eid').val(ui.item.eid);                         
                return false;
            }           
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

As you can see from the screen shot there is not value posted from this form. How do i set these displayed value as input field value.

I have looked in the jquery-ui api documentation but have not found this specific scenario.

TIA

Comment: If you are seeing the values you selected in the autocomplete dropdown, _in_ your form fields - then the autocomplete plugin has already correctly done it's job at this point. So there must either be something wrong with your form itself then, or with how you are submitting it (if that doesn't happen the "normal" way, but some JavaScript/AJAX is involved.)

Comment: The autocomplete function is working fine. but the values are not stored/posted with the  form. That is the issue.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said. And the rest of what I said should have implied, that you need to give us more details about the mentioned aspects of the problem then.

Comment: Oh I see. I missed to upload the code behind my form.  I will edit my question and upload it. sorry for that

Comment: @CBroe i updated my question added the code for form and script

Comment: Only form fields with a `name` attribute become part of the form submission data set. You neglected to actually give a name to any of them but the submit button.

Comment: My humble request to withdraw the down vote  (whoever down voted ) as not providing the front-end code was an honest mistake. I intended to include the vote but somehow missed it.